# What is the difference between apache.http and apache.commons.httpclient libraries?

Tags: android, http, libraries

When to use one or the other? 
I am programing for Android.

Answer (score 3):

Android has neither, so it does not really matter. Use `org.apache.http.*` classes in Android, since they are built into the OS.

Classes with `commons.httpclient` in their package refer to the original Apache Jakarta Commons HttpClient code base. Android has not had these classes in it for about three years, and the newer `org.apache.http.*` classes are what's current, both inside and outside of Android.